# SQL help for beginner

Tags: sql, count, average

I need a query which returns the number of sportsman in each team.

It should only display teams with a name longer than the average length of names and surnames of sportsman.

I have two tables **teams** and **sportmans**.

Here's what I tried:

```
SELECT TIMOVI,SPORTISTI COUNT(IME_PREZIME)
FROM TIMOVI
JOIN SPORTISTI
  ON SIFRA=TIM,
GROUP BY TIMOVI
WHERE LENGTH(naziv)> ((AVG(LENGHT(ime_preizime)))/2)
```

Comment: SELECT TIMOVI,SPORTISTI
COUNT(IME_PREZIME)
FROM TIMOVI JOIN SPORTISTI ON SIFRA=TIM,
GROUP BY TIMOVI
WHERE LENGTH(naziv)> ((AVG(LENGHT(ime_preizime)))/2)

Comment: I have two tables team and sportsman

Comment: TEAM has code PK, name, date of found

Comment: Please edit your question and show the table data.

Comment: SPORTSMAN has #number PK, name and surname and age

Comment: TEAM - 1 SPORTSMAN- M

Comment: There is no data currently. I have only structure

Comment: Please don't **comment** your question here. Click **edit**, update the question with detailed information and show the table structure. You may not have data in your database currently, but show us some records as example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a query like this:

```
SELECT t.name, COUNT(s.id)
FROM team t
INNER JOIN sportsman s ON s.team = t.id
WHERE LENGTH(t.name) > (
  SELECT AVG(LENGTH(s2.name)) FROM sportsman s2
)
GROUP BY t.id
```

For schema like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sportsman (
  id INTEGER,
  team INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE team (
  id INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(50)
);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f739/1)

Comment: It's been a while since I have entered this site and I have not noticed your answer. Thank you for your answer.